# I have edited this program that is supposed to calculate a business connection and a residential connection

Tags: vb.net

For residential customers it is 4.50 processing fee,30 basic service fee and 5 per channel. For business customers processing fee = 16.50 basicservice fee is 80 for the first 10 connections after 4 for each additional and 50 per channel
 I have edited this program that has to make use of two functions. A business connection and a residential connection,I am suppose to display 3 error messages,Premium Channels is a required field,Customer Type is a required field and  If a business checkbox is checked an error message is suppose to display saying  Business Customers must select 1 or more Connection." can anyone tell me why just  the Business Customers must select 1 or more Connections does not display.(the other two does display)

[image: listboximage]

' make a function so all data passed through is valid

```
Private Function Data_Validated_ok() As Boolean



    Dim intErrCount As Integer
    Dim strErrMessage As String = String.Empty
    Dim ctrlError As New Collection




    ' make sure Premium channel is selected

    If Me.lstPremium.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        intErrCount = intErrCount + 1
        strErrMessage &= intErrCount & ". Premium Channels is a required field." _
        & vbCrLf
        ctrlError.Add(lstPremium.SelectedIndex)
    End If
    ' make sure a customer type is selected in the Radioboxes

    If radBusiness.Checked = False And
                radResidential.Checked = False Then
        intErrCount = intErrCount + 1
        strErrMessage &= intErrCount & ".Customer Type is a required field." _
         & vbCrLf
        ctrlError.Add(radBusiness.Checked, CStr(radResidential.Checked))
    End If

    ' make sure a business customer checks at least one option in the listbox

    If radBusiness.Checked = True And Me.lstConnections.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        intErrCount = intErrCount + 1
        strErrMessage &= intErrCount & ". Business Customers must select 1 or more Connection." _
        & vbCrLf
        ctrlError.Add(lstConnections.SelectedIndex)
    End If

    'if any errors display a message box with the list of errors
    If intErrCount > 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(strErrMessage, "Validation Rule(s)", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)



        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: In your return statement, try and put brackets in the right spots. Are you sure you used the correct [order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)? Also, it seems that in `CalcBuisnesssTotalDue` you never use the `connections` parameter. Is that your intention?

Comment: It is hard to understand your code without running it. If you could explain your code with more details using comments it would be easier to help you.

Comment: no it was not my intention to leave out connections. thank you for that observation  Eminem  As far as return statement do you mean like this (residentialp * Residentialbasic) sorry i am new to functions.  phil652 I just need to calculate the bill for example if a business customer checks 12 connections in the listbox should my logic be Processingfee+channelfee +premiumchannels *  4? If you are a business customer if connections are >10 you have to pay 4 dollars for every extra connection.